# Forgot password API is not working in magento 2.x

Tags: php, rest, magento2

I need to reset the password[Forgot Password] using below  REST API,

URL : `{{base_url}}/index.php/rest/V1/customers/password`

Method : `PUT`

body :

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "template": "Forgot Password",
    "websiteId": 1
}
```

Getting the  below response,

```
{
    "message": "Invalid value of \"%value\" provided for the %fieldName field.",
    "parameters": {
        "value": "Forgot Password",
        "fieldName": "email type"
    }
}
```

Please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working when i give template as **email_reset**

```
{
   "email": "test@email.com",
   "template": "email_reset",
   "websiteId": 1
}
```

[The [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html) for this api not correct."**email_reset**" is not real template which you can create in admin. It is constant which I found in AccountManagenet.php]

[Refer](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5513)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

{
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "template": "Forgot Password",
        "websiteId": 1
  }
If you problem don't be solved look at `Stores -> Settings -> All Stores -> Website`. In URL you can find your WebSiteID. 
By default MainWebSite have id=1.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "template": "Forgot Password",
    "websiteId": 1
}
```

that's worked for me with "Forgot Password" template and "websiteID":1.